# Matlab - camera equations solver

Tags: matlab, camera, equation-solving

I have troubles solving camera equation in matlab. I am given two points and two camera matrices and my task is to find lambda , and U . I created a function as follows and now I am trying to find a way to solve this. Can anyone please help me with that?
Thanks

```
function U = minimal_triangulation(Ps, us)
% Takes in two camera matrices -> Ps and two image points -> us
% Outputs a triangulateion of a 3D point. 
%The image points are a 2 × 2 array whereas the camera matrices
% is a cell list with one camera matrix in each cell.
% we have two equations , with two unknown variables as :
% lambda*u1 = P1*U , lambda*u2 = P2*U and we search for lambda, U
u1 = [us(1,1); us(2,1) ; 1]
u2 = [us(1,2); us(2,2) ; 1]
syms l1 l2 l3 U1 U2 U3
lambda = [l1 l2 l3]
U = [U1;U2;U3;1];
P1 = Ps{1}
P2 = Ps{2}
eq1 = lambda*u1==P1*U ;
eq2 = lambda*u2==P2*U ;
sol = solve([eq1, eq2], [l1, l2, l3, U1, U2, U3]);
U = [sol.U1 ; sol.U3 ; sol.U3 ; 1]
end
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Sorry beaker, but I posted my question and MY SOLUTION. It is solved, the problem is just that matlab is giving me "empty syms" as answer, and that is my question, not for anyone to solve this instead of me..